# Primeng ptable v9 columnResize mousedown even stopPropagation - to prevent drag&drop for parent element

Tags: angular, primeng

I have imperfection during primeng ptable column-resize event.

Some layout area (parent div) has a possibility to drag-and-drop widgets. If widget contains primeng ptable with columnsResize functionality - on resizing column parent also starts dragging while widget as well.

Question: How to keep widget drap&drop from parent perspective (mousedown - mousemove- mouseup) but exclude columnsResize mousemove for primeng v9 ptable ?

```
<div class="parent-with-drag-and-drop-for-widets-inside">
  <some-widget class="ptable-inside"></some-widget>
  <some-widget class="ptable-inside"></some-widget>
  <some-widget class="ptable-inside"></some-widget>
  <some-widget class="ptable-inside"></some-widget>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found workaround how to do that:

1. p-table has special element between header columns - span with class="ui-column-resize"
2. In some-widget component class in ngOnInit hook I pick all such elements and addEventListener on mousedown event. And then all event.stopPropagation. Do not forget to removeEventListener in ngOnDestroy hook method.

   ```
    class SomeWidgetClass implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      private stopPropagationFunc = (event:Event) => event.stopPropagation();

      resizerElems: Element[] = [];

      constructor(hostElem: ElementRef){}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.resizerElems = Array.from(this.hostElem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.ui-column-resizer')) || [];

        this.resizerElems.forEach(elem => {
         elem.addEventListener('mousedown', this.stopPropagationFunc);
        });
      }    

     ngOnDestroy() {
      this.resizerElems.forEach(elem => {
       return elem.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.stopPropagationFunc);
      });
     }

   }
   ```